# Best way to SELECT one column based on the count of another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access as to learn SQL, and have a query that I seem to be hung up on.

I'm trying to find the average fee for suppliers in a city, but only if there are between 2 and 4 suppliers within that province.  I have been able to produce the results in different pieces, but can't put them into one singular query.

Columns are

Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | City | Province | Fee

To get the average fee for provinces that have between 2 and 4 I have this

```
SELECT  Province, COUNT(*) AS [Suppliers in Province], AVG(Fee) AS [Average Fee]
FROM Suppliers_t
GROUP BY Province
HAVING COUNT (Supplier_ID) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 ;
```

And to get Averages based on the city I have this,

```
SELECT City, AVG(Fee) AS [Average Fee]
FROM Suppliers_t
GROUP BY City
;
```

Any tips on how to bring the two of them into one solution?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try to format code  for better read experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, new to this and you're right way easier to read!

Comment: You're welcome. I would like to edit that myself but the suggested edit queue is full; :)

Comment: Build a report with subreports. Exactly what do you expect the output to look like? - edit your question. Those two queries could be UNION'ed if that would meet your requirement.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "SELECT one column based on the count of another".

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a very easy answer

```
SELECT City, AVG(Fee) AS Supplier Avg Fee
FROMSuppliers_t
WHERE Province IN
(
    SELECT Province
    FROM Suppliers_t 
    GROUP BY Province 
    HAVIGN COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 4
)
GROUP BY City;
```

I wasn't using IN, so my subquery was not related to my query.